# Newline-terminating input loop not exiting in C

Tags: c

I'll preface this with the fact that this is for a homework assignment, so I'm just trying to understand what's going wrong not necessarily exactly how to fix it. I'm working in C, taking a name and grade from the user to create/manipulate structs and use a stack. This `while` loop won't exit and it isn't reaching the testing print statement at the bottom. `line`, `name`, `cGrade`, and `fullData` are all character arrays, `maxGrade` and `numGrade` are both `double` variables, `s` is a stack and `item` is a `void*`:

```
while ((fgets(line, SIZE, stdin)) != NULL && line[0] != '\n') {
    if (sscanf(line, "%s %s", name, cGrade) == 2) {
        numGrade = atoi(cGrade);
        fullData[0] = 0;
        if (numGrade >= 0 && numGrade <= 100) {
            strcat(fullData, name);
            strcat(fullData, " ");
            strcat(fullData, cGrade);
            printf("Added %s\n", fullData);

            item = name;
            push(s, item);

            if (numGrade > maxGrade) {
                maxGrade = numGrade;
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            printf("ERROR: Grade must be between 0 and 100\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Outside if: line[0] = %c", line[0]);
}
```

Edit: adding a screenshot of the output
[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjL53.png)

Edit: Adding push code

```
void push(stack s, void* item){
      stackelement* e = malloc(sizeof(stackelement*));
      e->contents = malloc(sizeof(void*));
      e->next = malloc(sizeof(stackelement*));

      e->contents = item;
      e->next = s->top;
      s->top = e;

}
```

Here's the struct definition as well. I was given this for the assignment so I'm not allowed to change it.

```
struck stackelementS {
       void* contents;
       struct stackelementS* next;
}

typedef struct stackelementS stackelement;

struct stackS {
       stackelement* top; 

}

typedef struct stackS* stack;
```

Comment: `item = name;` only copies a pointer to a buffer whose content will get overwritten.

Comment: Please don't change the posted code on-the-fly unless you made a mistake in posting it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It helps a lot if you create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  It would not add much code to your question, but would resolve questions like "how are the variables defined".  What happens if you omit the `item` and `s` variables, and the call to `push`?

Comment: The behavior depends on your input.  What is the input?

Comment: @WeatherVane: up until there are answers, it is OK to fix the code, especially when it isn't yet an MCVE.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah, the function accepts a void* so I'm moving the pointer to the name string into void* item to avoid the compiler yelling at me.

Comment: Even C++ converts an 'anything pointer' into a `void *` automatically.  C does the opposite conversion automatically; C++ does not.  The compiler should not be shouting at you.

Comment: What I mean, is that if you `push(s, item);` twice, for two names, they both point to the same buffer, so the same data.

Comment: @WilliamPursell As the code runs the user enters the name and grade separated by a space at the command line. I read in the whole line as a character array

Comment: If you have `double numGrade;`, why do you use `atoi()` rather than `strtod()` or `atof()`?

Comment: If the loop is not terminating when you enter a blank line, then you are probably overwriting data. Replace the `strcat` with appropriate `strncat` calls, and show the code for `push`.

Comment: Could an unexpected `'\r'` get in your way?

Comment: `#define struck struct` and `#define stackelementS StackElement`, _etc_, before including that header that you are not supposed to touch is a way to get around the syntax error and terrible naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the simple fact that using sscanf doesn't include the escape character `\0` in the returned string which I assume was messing up some of the string functions. I added a `char *end; *end = '\0';` and used strcat() to append it to the name and cGrade. I fixed some of the errors suggested in the comments and it cleaned up the code a lot.
Here's the fixed code:

```
while(fgets(line, SIZE, stdin) != NULL && line[0] != '\n'){                                                                     
        if(sscanf(line, "%s %s", name, cGrade) == 2){                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                strcat(name, end);                                                                                                      
                strcat(cGrade, end);                                                                                                    
                numGrade = strtod(cGrade, &ptr);                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                if(numGrade >=0 && numGrade<= 100){                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                       push(s, line);                                                                                                          
                       printf("Added student %s with grade %s to the stack\n", name, cGrade);                                                                                                                                                                          
                       if(numGrade > maxGrade){                                                                                                        
                             maxGrade = numGrade;                                                                                            
                       }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                       i++;                                                                                                            
                }                                                                                                                       
                else{                                                                                                                           
                       printf("ERROR: Grade must be between 0 and 100, please re-enter the information\n");                            }                                                                                                               
                }                                                                                                               
    }
```